# How to use a function when I'm Redirect in React router v6

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Using React Router Dom I have run into a problem.

Suppose I want to enter a profile page, but the user must be logged in before entering. So, in this case I'm using Navigate to redirect the user to Home, in case they're not logged in. But my problem is that I want to show an alert to the user specifying that he must log in first before entering the profile page.

```
import React from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Link,
  Route,
  Routes,
  Navigate,
} from "react-router-dom";
import NotFoundPage from "./pages/404/NotFoundPage";
import AboutPage from "./pages/about-faqs/AboutPage";
import HomePage from "./pages/home/HomePage";
import ProfilePage from "./pages/profile/ProfilePage";
import ProtectedRoute from "./pages/Protected-Routes/protectedRoute";
import TaskDetailPage from "./pages/tasks/TaskDetailPage";
import TasksPage from "./pages/tasks/TasksPage";

function AppRoutingOne() {

  const logged  = false;

  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <ul style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "space-between" }}>
          <li>
            <Link to="/"> Home </Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/about"> About </Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/faqs"> FAQs </Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <main>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
          <Route path="/about" element={<AboutPage />} />
          <Route path="/faqs" element={<AboutPage />} />

          //This is the part of my problem, in this case. How do I display an "alert()" inside the ternary operator?

          <Route
            path="/profile"
            element={logged ? <ProfilePage /> : <Navigate to="/" replace /> }
          /> 


          <Route path="/task" element={<TasksPage />} />
          <Route path="/task/:id" element={<TaskDetailPage />} />

          {/* 404 - Page Not Found */}
          <Route path="*" element={<NotFoundPage />} />
        </Routes>
      </main>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default AppRoutingOne;
```

Answer (score 0):

I edit add to your code , and add new Component :

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Link,
  Route,
  Routes,
  Navigate,
} from "react-router-dom";
import NotFoundPage from "./pages/404/NotFoundPage";
import AboutPage from "./pages/about-faqs/AboutPage";
import HomePage from "./pages/home/HomePage";
import ProfilePage from "./pages/profile/ProfilePage";
import ProtectedRoute from "./pages/Protected-Routes/protectedRoute";
import TaskDetailPage from "./pages/tasks/TaskDetailPage";
import TasksPage from "./pages/tasks/TasksPage";

function AppRoutingOne() {

  const logged  = false;

  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <ul style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "space-between" }}>
          <li>
            <Link to="/"> Home </Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/about"> About </Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/faqs"> FAQs </Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <main>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
          <Route path="/about" element={<AboutPage />} />
          <Route path="/faqs" element={<AboutPage />} />

          //This is the part of my problem, in this case. How do I display an "alert()" inside the ternary operator?

          <Route
            path="/profile"
            element={<ProfileController logged={logged} /> }
          /> 


          <Route path="/task" element={<TasksPage />} />
          <Route path="/task/:id" element={<TaskDetailPage />} />

          {/* 404 - Page Not Found */}
          <Route path="*" element={<NotFoundPage />} />
        </Routes>
      </main>
    </Router>
  );
}


export default AppRoutingOne;
```

in this component you check logged props. if logged is false you can show alert to user :

```
function ProfileCntroller({logged}){
    useEffect(()=>{
        if(!logged){
            alert('alert text');
        }
    },[]);

    if(logged){
        return <ProfilePage /> }
    else{
        return <Navigate to="/" replace />
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the need for a useEffect when you can alert before returning?

Answer (score 0):

App.js

```js
import React from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Link,
  Route,
  Routes,
  Navigate,
  Outlet
} from "react-router-dom";
import NotFoundPage from "./pages/404/NotFoundPage";
import AboutPage from "./pages/about-faqs/AboutPage";
import HomePage from "./pages/home/HomePage";
import ProfilePage from "./pages/profile/ProfilePage";
import ProtectedRoute from "./pages/Protected-Routes/protectedRoute";
import TaskDetailPage from "./pages/tasks/TaskDetailPage";
import TasksPage from "./pages/tasks/TasksPage";

function Protected({ children }) { 
// you may want to store isSignedIn value in a reactive state, may be  use redux etc
  const isSignedIn = someReactiveState; 
  if (!isSignedIn) {
    alert("You should log in !")
    return <Navigate to="/" replace />;
  }
  return <Outlet />;
}


function AppRoutingOne() {

  const logged  = false;

  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <ul style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "space-between" }}>
          <li>
            <Link to="/"> Home </Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/about"> About </Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/faqs"> FAQs </Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <main>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
          <Route path="/about" element={<AboutPage />} />
          <Route path="/faqs" element={<AboutPage />} />
            {/*All Protected Routes here ! */}
          <Route element={<Protected />}>
            <Route path="/profile" element={<ProfilePage />} />
          </Route>
      


          <Route path="/task" element={<TasksPage />} />
          <Route path="/task/:id" element={<TaskDetailPage />} />

          {/* 404 - Page Not Found */}
          <Route path="*" element={<NotFoundPage />} />
        </Routes>
      </main>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default AppRoutingOne;
```

[Outlet](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/outlet) will be the component that have been in the children route !

Comment: Don't issue the `alert` as an unintentional side-effect.